# mapTypeControlOptions buttonSize not working

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I can shift the Map/Satellite button but can not resize it. This runs ok but no affect on the buttons! Any help please?

```
  mapTypeControl: true,
  mapTypeControlOptions: {
  style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
  buttonSize: google.maps.Point(80,40),
  position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER
},
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `buttonSize` option for [`MapTypeControlOptions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapTypeControlOptions)

If you want to modify those buttons, you need to create your own [custom controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls) that change the mapType and hide the API version.